# Facebook graph api with og:image does not display the correct image

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, metadata

I added the facebook graph api meta tags to my blog (head or body):

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $url; ?>"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $fbtitle ?>"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="<?php echo $fbtype; ?>"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://<?php echo $fblink; ?>"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echo $fbblogname; ?>"/>
```

When I added a link to my timeline, it doesn't display the selected image (og:image), but let me select from all images of the link. It's just list the images, but the first one is not the selected.

What should I do with that?

Answer (score 3):

Enter your page link here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

It will probably tell you what is wrong.

Can you also share an example of what the value of $url is? - it should be a full image url.

Comment: I solved this thx! this meta do the job:
    <link href="<?php echo $url; ?>" rel="image_src"/>

Comment: When you post something fb crawl the site the images, and save them, and when others share it, fb loads the last image array, fb doesn't check the meta tags again (I added later then first share). fools...